# Topological minor and independence number

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

If $G$ and $X$ are graphs with $G=TX$, ($X$ is a topological minor of $G$) is there any sort of relation between $\alpha(G)$ and $\alpha(X)$ (the independence numbers of both). In addition if finding the largest independent set in $G$ is NP-hard is it always the case that finding it in $X$ will also be NP-hard? I suspect an answer to my second question may provide an answer to my first. I know that the smallest vertex cover problem and maximum independent set problem are related so I also want to extend my question to vertex covers, is there a relationship between the smallest vertex cover of $G$ and the smallest vertex cover of $X$?

Comment: If I'm understanding topological minors correctly, there is no relationship between $\alpha(G)$ and $\alpha(X)$  unless you involve other graph parameters.  That is, $X$ could be a star with a large independent set and $G$ could be a large complete graph with a small independent set.  Or vice versa, $G$ could be a star union a complete graph, and $X$ could be a complete graph.  But perhaps with other graph parameters a relationship could be found.

Comment: How about in the case of vertex covers then? I would've thought the relationship would've been more clear since each edge is replaced by a path of which the internal vertices have degree 2.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that $\tau(G) \geq \tau(X)$:  if you have a collection of vertices that cover the edges of $G$, then they cover the edges of $X$ as well.  There is a difficulty in that some of the vertices needed in the cover are not in $X$, but in the middle of an edge of $X$.  However, just take either endpoint of such an edge and you still have the same number of vertices, or potentially fewer, covering all the edges.